# Enable the request log, even when a router script is used for the PHP built-in web server

Tags: php, regex, url-routing, front-controller

PHP's built in web server allows "router scripts" to be used, allowing for rewriting URLs internally.

The problem with such a router script is the fact that whenever it actually handles a file instead of letting PHP handle it, this causes the request log output for that request to be suppressed. For example, consider the following script:

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/^\/(js|css)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1) {
  return false;
}
else {
  echo 'hello world!'
}
```

This causes requests for `/js/*` and `/css/*` to be logged on the console; whereas requests for any other URLs simply skip logging the request.

How can I enable logging of all requests to the console?

Comment: Which console did you mean?

Answer (score 3):

router.php :

```
if (preg_match('/^\/(js|css)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1) {
    return false;
}
else {
    $stdErr = fopen("php://stderr",'w+');
    fwrite($stdErr, 'LogRequest:'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."\n");
    echo 'hello world!1';
}
```

Server start: `php -S localhost:8000 router.php 2>&1`

To log response headers:

```
if (preg_match('/^\/(js|css)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1) {
    return false;
}
else {
    ob_start() 
    $stdErr = fopen("php://stderr",'w+');
    fwrite($stdErr, 'Request:'.json_encode($_SERVER)."\n");
    try {
      echo 'hello world!1';
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        http_response_code(500);
    }
    $response = ob_get_clean();
    fwrite($stdErr, 'Response:'.json_encode([ http_response_code(),headers_list() ])."\n");
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike the built-in webserver's logging, it doesn't cause the response HTTP status to be logged (which is kinda the point of the log...)

Comment: i think the challenging part was to write to the console from the else case, if you want more than quick view about what happening i avdise to consider to put a real webserver before php, anyway i've added a sample for response code logging

Answer (score 2):

In your log you can see errors from php build-in server, so you can do like @cske, but i think you should stick another approach.You can use own logger and write explicitly info to this log. The best logger right now it is [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), so you don't have to reveal the wheel. Here my example:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// Create a log channel.
$log = new Logger('general');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('/var/log/php/general.log', Logger::INFO));

if (preg_match('/^\/(js|css)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1) {
    $log->error('Invalid request.');
    return false;
} else {
    $log->info('Success.');
    echo 'hello world!';
}
```

I hope you agree that it looks much clear and simple.

Also when you will move from php build-in server to for example nginx your code will work correctly. You need just run in another window into terminal `tail -f /var/log/php/general.log` and you will observe behavior of your script like in window with php build-in server.

PS: I hope you don't use php build-in server in production

Comment: if the problem would have been how to log to file with php, my first though was similar log to file and merge `tail` and `php -S` output, but sdterr solved the problem so there is even no need for a writeable filepath